# How do find difference between 2 dates in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

This question is w.r.t Python 2.7.

I have the following time data in a CSV file - the format is MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffffff. I would like to find difference between 2 dates. The difference between 2 dates is usually in milliseconds.

I tried to use the following API to convert the str to a datetime object,

```
time_info = datetime.strptime(time_data_from_csv, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

I get the following error -

```
ValueError: time data '"12-31-2018 12:21:12.315948"' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

I also tried - `'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'`, to no avail (not sure if it was the right usage). Here, `time_data_from_csv` is a string variable. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, you state the timestamp is in one format, try to use a different, un-matching format to parse it, and get an error saying it doesn't match. What's the question? (And you state the CSV data separates date components with "/", which doesn't line up with the code or example data.)

Comment: I updated my question, please check. I tried with the millisecond formatter too "%f". Did not work. I am suspecting if the single quote around the string data is '"12-31-2018 12:21:12.315948"', is causing trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. As I suspected, somehow the double-quotes were causing the trouble.
I solved it by adding double-quotes to my format string. Thanks for all your attention and help!

```
datetime.strptime(time_data_from_csv, '"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f"')
```

Comment: "Somehow"? They're characters not in the format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the double quotes in the format string since your `time_data_from_csv` variable has them, according to the error message:

```
time_info = datetime.strptime(time_data_from_csv, '"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f"')
```

Comment: Hi blhsing, thanks for that. As I mentioned in my updated question, that does not seem to work when I use the variable. The error has a single quote ' and double quote around the date, is it the problem?

Comment: Yep, as you rightly pointed out. That was the trouble. I fixed it. I answered it too. Thanks for your quick response, appreciate it!